# django jsi18n and jquery ui datepicker format compatibility

Tags: django, jquery-ui, internationalization, jquery-ui-datepicker

Im trying to use jquery ui datepicker in localized Django app. I would like to format date based on language (due to custom validation for different languages). In django, there is js helper django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog which returns required formats, but these formats are not compatible with jquery ui datepicker dateFormat attribute.

for example, django gives this:

```
formats['SHORT_DATE_FORMAT'] = 'd.m.Y';

formats['DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS'] = ['%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M', '%d.%m.%Y', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d'];`
```

But none of those are usable for jquery ui datepicker dateFormat attr. Datepicker requires different format.

Is there any solution for this problem? e.g. django(python) to datepicker parser? Thank you for any solution. At least, i can write my own djangoToDatepicker parser, but i would like to have cleaner solution.

Comment: You can change the widget of the datetime field. And this could have the needy format

Comment: Well, i think im going to write custom templatetag for this with some string replace functions :-X

Comment: I use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/). It might help you.